# Segmentation of MP4 generation M3u8 failed with HLS iOS

Tags: ios, m3u8, http-live-streaming

I am a iOS developer,I tried to cut a MP4 file with the HLS in the terminal to generate a M3u8,but the cutting is the result of failure.

```
AppledeMacBook-Pro:stream apple$ mediafilesegmenter -t 100 -f hls3/ 2.mp4
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.027: Using floating point is not backward compatible to iOS 4.1 or earlier devices
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.029: Processing file /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/2.mp4
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.234: Finalized /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/hls3/fileSequence0.ts
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.234: segment bitrate 410.82 kbits/sec is new max
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.362: Finalized /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/hls3/fileSequence1.ts
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.362: segment bitrate 464.69 kbits/sec is new max
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.492: Finalized /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/hls3/fileSequence2.ts
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.621: Finalized /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/hls3/fileSequence3.ts
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.741: Finalized /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/hls3/fileSequence4.ts
Oct 16 2014 20:39:53.880: Finalized /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/hls3/fileSequence5.ts
Oct 16 2014 20:39:54.016: Finalized /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/hls3/fileSequence6.ts
Oct 16 2014 20:39:54.075: Error with H.264 frame - offset 4 + nal length 2147642384 greater than frame size 105
Oct 16 2014 20:39:54.075: couldn't transform frame
Oct 16 2014 20:39:54.079: Finalized /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/hls3/fileSequence7.ts
Oct 16 2014 20:39:54.079: average bit rate is 393.16 kbits/sec - max file bit rate is 464.69 kbits/sec
```

Look at the prompting problem in

```
Oct 16 2014 20:39:54.075: Error with H.264 frame - offset 4 + nal length 2147642384 greater than frame size 105
Oct 16 2014 20:39:54.075: couldn't transform frame
Oct 16 2014 20:39:54.079: Finalized /Library/WebServer/Documents/stream/hls3/fileSequence7.ts
Oct 16 2014 20:39:54.079: average bit rate is 393.16 kbits/sec - max file bit rate is 464.69 kbits/sec
```

Why would such a situation, how to solve it? Thank you!